# Java Jar within a Jar

Tags: java, jar

Im trying to make my jar load a driver that will be stored inside it. Is this possible without having the user download any additional programs. I've read on another post about One-Jar but I'm not sure I understand how it works. Will The user have to download one-jar too?

I downloaded one-jar but when I run it nothing happens :S. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use a sar/war/ear etc (instead of a jar) and put all your stuff in there

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation of one-jar instead of just running it?

Comment: If you're using Maven, there's an answer [here]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a shell script to append all the jars in a directory to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Maven Assembly Plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

And build with the descriptor "jar-with-dependencies"

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

It is pretty easy.